# Gaussian function with dependent variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian

Through my studies so far, I was able to understand the Gaussian function when variables are independent in a normal distribution, but I cannot think of cases where they are not independent.
I would like to know examples of expressions and conditions when variables are not independent in Gaussian functions.

Comment: What is a Gaussian function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution